# JwtAuthorizationFilter implementtaion not working

Tags: spring, spring-data

In summary JwtAuthorizationFilter is not working.

If I leave //filterChain.doFilter(request, response) commented out I correctly get a 200 but the body is empty, which means two things:
1) The Controller/Response from the controller is executed but not the logic on it.
2) The function getAuthentication() correctly reads the Claims/token

The issue happens if I uncomment the line //filterChain.doFilter(request, response) because I get a 405. That line should be uncommented for the filter chain to exeute completely and get a response body with content.

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,    
 FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(request);
    if (authentication == null) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    **//filterChain.doFilter(request, response);**
}

Function in the controller:
@GetMapping("/foo")
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public MyObject retrieve(@RequestBody MyModel obj) {
    //code here is never called
}

For reference, this is my security config:
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/bar").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(new AnotherFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

}

What Am I doing wrong?
```

Comment: What authorities are you giving to the user?

Comment: I am not adding any since I noticed none were present and I didn ont need to put any:
        List<String> roles = user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());

      String token = Jwts.builder()
                           .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey)
                           .setSubject(user.getUsername())
                           .setExpiration(new  Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+Long.parseLong("3600000")))
                           //.claim("rol", roles)
                           .compact();

Comment: I commented out  //.claim("rol", roles) because there were no roles in user (i.e.:  auth.getPrincipal())  I did not need to put any.

Should I parse user.getAuthorities() in a different way? or should I add something there for  filterChain.doFilter(request, response); to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to say that I clean up the build, restart the IDE and worked.
Maybe there was some cache not allowing the JWT filter to work properly.
Thanks,